# How many times will we cross?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This happened to me today in the morning.

I was jogging in my apartment area. Its a circular track.
I make 10 rounds in alternate walk and run pattern,in anti-clockwise direction. So the first round is basically walking, and second is running and third is a walk and so on and so forth.

An old lady was also walking but in the clockwise direction. I crossed her 3 times in 2 rounds. Then she stopped her exercise.

I wanted to know, that given just this much of data, Is it really possible to calculate number of times we will cross each other "for my entire exercise routine" ? How?

My thought process:

If she was walking with speed $a$ and I with $b$,and I crossed her thrice in 2 rounds, I believe she must have completed at least 1 of hers.Then,$a$ must be relatively less than be $b$ if not too low.
But I cannot arrive to a number. Please advise.

Comment: why 1 close vote? May I know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting thing about this question is how *little* information it gives
about the woman's speed.

For convenience in describing what happens during your exercise, let's suppose
someone has made $100$ marks at regular intervals around the track, numbereed
$0$ to $99$ consecutively in counterclockwise order, so that in one circuit
around the track you start at $0$, then cross $1$, then $2$, and so forth until
you reach $0$ again.

Suppose at the start of your first circuit, the woman was standing at mark $1$,
and by the end of your second circuit she was at mark $99$.
So you cross her path once near $1$, then in your second circuit somewhere closer to $0$,
and finally near the end of your second circuit near $99$.
You have done $2$ full circuits in the same time she has moved $\frac{1}{50}$
of the way around the track, so your average speed is $100$ times hers.

On the other hand, suppose she was at $99$ when you started your first circuit
and at $1$ when you ended your second circuit. If she walks at $49/100$ times your
average speed, she can do this, and you still will have met her only three times
in your two circuits.

In the limit, her average speed could be anywhere between $0$ and $\frac12$ 
your average speed.  So even assuming she continued walking with a constant speed
during the entire time you made your ten circuits, there is a very wide range
of possible number of times you might cross paths.